# Module is not available - Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I have installed [angular-stripe](https://github.com/bendrucker/angular-stripe) and have included it in  controller as follows

```
  angular
  .module('payments', [
    "angular-stripe"
  ])
  .config(function (stripeProvider) {
    stripeProvider.setPublishableKey('my_key')
  })
```

But the following error is thrown.

> Module 'angular-stripe' is not available! You either misspelled the
>   module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that
>   you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

```
(function (app) {
  'use strict';
  app.registerModule('payments');
}(ApplicationConfiguration));
```

Comment: Did you included it in your application?

Comment: I have installed it using npm install angular-stripe. How can I include it in the app. It is under node_modules

Comment: I think you have not injected proper order.

Comment: do you have any module.js file to add this module?

Comment: @Dixit - No. I don't have any model

Comment: have added before like this 'ngAnimate','ngSanitize','ui.router' module in any of the file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include this script in your application :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
```

And `angular-stripe.js` :

```
<script src="npm-folder/angular-stripe.js"></script>
```

I hope this would help you!